# How to code-sign Mac app for outside of App Store from command line?

Tags: macos, code-signing

I've followed the official Apple documentation to code-sign my app from Xcode GUI, which works, i.e., `spctl -a -v` gives me:

```
$ spctl -a -v HelloCodeSign.app
HelloCodeSign.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

However, when code-signing the clean build of the same app from the codesign command-line tool, I got the following errors:

```
$ codesign --force --sign "Developer ID Application: MyCompany, Inc." -vv HelloCodeSign.app
HelloCodeSign.app: replacing existing signature
HelloCodeSign.app: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
```

Tried many tutorials and StackOverflow posts but none of them helped.

Are there step-by-step instructions on how to code-sign from command line? I don't think Apple has an equally detailed instruction for the CLI  version as their GUI version of the workflow:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

I tried to work with this tech note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

and the "requirement syntax" section seems to be related to the error messages above. However, there are no instructions on how to find out the values for those syntax to work with a particular app. So it seems useless.

**UPDATE**

I followed this tech note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG2

and used this command to look deeper into the errors:

```
$ codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' /path/to/HelloCodeSign.app
/path/to/HelloCodeSign.app: valid on disk
/path/to/HelloCodeSign.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
```

and regarding the error message, the tech note says:

```
This error indicates that the profile used to sign the app is missing its submission entitlement which can occur for example when a development Provisioning Profile is used to the sign the app instead of the intended distribution profile.
```

However, I'm pretty sure I used the right Developer ID to sign the app. There are only one Application ID and one Installer ID there and I used the former.

**UPDATE 2**

I referred to the tech note and inspected the app's signature:

```
$ codesign -dvvv HelloCodeSign.app
Executable=HelloCodeSign.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloCodeSign
Identifier=com.mycompany.HelloCodeSign
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=233 flags=0x0(none) hashes=4+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=8ca384ad68378c9bcde24dc4c1778d36a0048362
Signature size=4318
Authority=Mac Developer: My TeamAgent (WB764F5QV6)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=May 25, 2015, 5:00:53 PM
Info.plist entries=22
TeamIdentifier=BCB4VLKTK5
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=5
Internal requirements count=1 size=192
```

Are these all requirements?? Should I add them to the `--requirments` switch?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using?  Does your app contain any dylibs, frameworks, or helper apps, which should be signed before the app as a whole?

Comment: @JWWalker I'm on OS X 10.10.3, Xcode 6.3. My app is an empty app straight up generated from Xcode project wizard, no code and nothing added.